# Why drop key-space data did not removed with its snapshot files from Disk?

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax

I used the `DROP KEYSPACE` command to perform a drop operation for my keyspace from cassandra cluster; the operation was successfully executed, but why weren't the data files for that keyspace (and its snapshots) removed?

Is there a way to drop keyspace and contextually remove from disk all files related to it?
Or should cassandra usersremove this data manually?

apache cassandra version : 2.0.10

Thanks & Regards

Sumit Thakur

Answer (score 3):

Snapshots can be removed manually, or with the `nodetool clearsnapshot` command.

> clearsnapshot                Remove the snapshot with the given name from the given keyspaces. If no snapshotName is specified we will remove all snapshots

You can [configure automatic snapshots](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__auto_snapshot) on drop using `auto_snapshot` in cassandra.yaml.